# NSComboBox with image and sections

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nscombobox

How to make a [NSComboBox](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscombobox?language=objc) with sections and icons, like the image picker of Xcode?[image: combo-box-with-image]

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Comment: Nope, AppKit doesn't seem to be too popular.